# Concatenation Code runs excruciatingly slowly google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My Concatenation  function is running excruciatingly slow, on only 28 rows of data it takes almost 4 minutes to run and I have other code I need to run so I hit the Max execution time in Google sheets

If I was running a similar process in Excel this would take maybe 15-30 sec

Everything is in memory, I can't see (with my limited knowledge of javascript) why my code is so slow

Thanks

[A Google sheet with data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1czaVGphpEFrMvWRDilWoQknEuJed5tiDkJsNIZqafAY/edit?usp=sharing)

```
//Sheet Name
//Values in Range to be overwritten by Header names
//List of Header names
//New Header Name 1
//New Header Name 2
function AsAboveSoBelow_Offers_Asks() {

   AsAboveSoBelow('Elements',
                  ["I can offer", "I have a ask"],
                  ["Header1","Header2","Header3","Header4","Header5","Header6",
                   "Header7","Header8","Header9","Header10","Header11",
                   "Header12","Header13","Header14"],
                   "Offers", 
                   "Asks");

}                  

function AsAboveSoBelow(shtName, arrPBV, arrHeaders, newHeader1, newHeader2) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s  = ss.getSheetByName(shtName);
var LC = s.getLastColumn();
var r  = s.getDataRange();
var v  = r.getValues();

var start = new Date(); 

var temp ="";
//Dim A
var A = [];
for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
     A[i] = [];
   for (var j = 0; j <= arrPBV.length - 1; j++) {
        A[i][j] = '';
   }
}

for(var e = 0; e <= arrPBV.length - 1; e++) {
    var search_Term  = arrPBV[e];

for(var row = 0; row < v.length; row++) {

  for(var col = 0; col <= arrHeaders.length - 1; col++) {
      var col2 = HTN(shtName,arrHeaders[col])

      var replace_Term = arrHeaders[col];

       if(v[row][col2-1].toString().indexOf(search_Term) > -1) {

          temp = temp + replace_Term + "|"

       }

     }

    //remove trailing pipe
     A[row][e] = temp.replace(/\|(?=\s*$)/, '')
       temp = ""

   }

 }

 A[0][0]= newHeader1
 A[0][1]= newHeader2

 s.getRange(1, v[0].length +1, v.length,A[0].length).setValues(A);

var end = new Date();
var executiontime = end - start;
Logger.log(executiontime);
};

//Helper function
function HTN(shtName,cheader){
var headers = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(shtName).getDataRange().getValues().shift();

var colindex = headers.indexOf(cheader);
return colindex+1;
}
```

Comment: Show your execution logs so we can see which steps are taking the most time. These can be found in `View > Execution transcript`.

Comment: I did not know about `execution logs`. I put them in the google sheet in the `execution logs` tab

Comment: You may have pasted them into the cell but not hit enter, no one can see them.

Comment: Sorry about that, you can see them now

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to post the log here instead? External links are ok, but  essential info should be in  the question itself.

Comment: Also explain what it is that your function does in plain English. Upon cursory reading, your helper function is a major issue... you're calling the same data values inside a double loop...

Comment: "it's all in memory" No, no it is not. You call for the whole spreadsheet data inside a 3x-nested for loop. That is undoubtedly the source of the issue. (Also, if you're just wanting the first row of values, why would you read ALL rows of data?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification point:

- In your script, `HTN()` is used as the for loops. And the function includes `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(shtName).getDataRange().getValues().shift();`. In your script, the Spreadsheet and `sheetName` are not changed. So `headers` is always same. I thought that this might be the main modification point.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

```
function AsAboveSoBelow_Offers_Asks() {
  AsAboveSoBelow(
    'Elements',
    ["I can offer", "I have a ask"],
    ["Header1","Header2","Header3","Header4","Header5","Header6","Header7","Header8","Header9","Header10","Header11","Header12","Header13","Header14"],
    "Offers", 
    "Asks"
  );
}

function AsAboveSoBelow(shtName, arrPBV, arrHeaders, newHeader1, newHeader2) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s  = ss.getSheetByName(shtName);
//  var LC = s.getLastColumn(); // It seems that this is not used.
  var r  = s.getDataRange();
  var v  = r.getValues();
  var start = new Date(); 
  var temp ="";
  //Dim A
  var A = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    A[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j <= arrPBV.length - 1; j++) {
      A[i][j] = '';
    }
  }
  var h = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]; // Added
  for(var e = 0; e <= arrPBV.length - 1; e++) {
    var search_Term  = arrPBV[e];
    for(var row = 0; row < v.length; row++) {
      for(var col = 0; col <= arrHeaders.length - 1; col++) {
        var col2 = h.indexOf(arrHeaders[col]) + 1; // Modified
        var replace_Term = arrHeaders[col];
        if(v[row][col2-1].toString().indexOf(search_Term) > -1) {
          temp = temp + replace_Term + "|"
        }
      }
      //remove trailing pipe
      A[row][e] = temp.replace(/\|(?=\s*$)/, '')
      temp = ""
    }
  }
  A[0][0]= newHeader1
  A[0][1]= newHeader2
  s.getRange(1, v[0].length +1, v.length,A[0].length).setValues(A);
  var end = new Date();
  var executiontime = end - start;
  Logger.log(executiontime);
};
```

#### Note:

- In my environment, the process time of the modified script was about 5 seconds.

If this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thank you. SO RELIEVED 

Comment: @xyz Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.